# Is onnegotiationneeded only fired from the offerer's side of a RtcPeerConnection

Tags: webrtc

I develop a chat system that uses WebRTC to let peers send video to each other. There are only ever two users in a chat. I've coded it so two RtcPeerConnections are created for each chat; one connection for outgoing video and one for incoming video.

I use the following code to handle when the connection needs to be renegotiated (new tracks added, network changes, etc) and I'm suspicious as to whether my approach may cause stability issues with the chat system going forward. I've left out the ICE candidate exchange and a bunch of other stuff in the code below for brevity - hopefully it still makes enough sense:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(mediaConstraints)
    .then(stream => {
        // outgoingPcContainer/incomingPcContainer encapsulates the RtcPeerConnection for the outgoing video
        outgoingPcContainer.pc = new RTCPeerConnection(iceServers);   

        outgoingPcContainer.pc.onnegotiationneeded = () => {
            if (outgoingPcContainer.isNegotiating) return;
            outgoingPcContainer.isNegotiating = true;

            outgoingPcContainer.pc.createOffer({
                offerToReceiveAudio: true,
                offerToReceiveVideo: true,
            });
                .then((offer) => {
                    return outgoingPcContainer.pc.setLocalDescription(offer);
                })
                .then(() => {
                    // Send SDP to the other user via signalling channel
                    invokeSignalRMethod('sendConnectionOffer', recipientId, outgoingPcContainer.pc.localDescription);
                })
                .finally(() => {
                    outgoingPcContainer.isNegotiating = false;
                });
        };

        stream.getTracks().forEach(track => 
            outgoingPcContainer.pc.addTrack(track, stream));
    }
```

Note that this event handler is only bound by the outgoing (offerer) RtcPeerConnection.

The recipient receives this offer and sends back an answer:

```
chatHub.on('connectionOffered', (offererId, desc) => {
    incomingPcContainer.pc = new RtcPeerConnection(iceServers);
    incomingPcContainer.pc.setRemoteDescription(desc)
        .then(() => incomingPcContainer.pc.createAnswer(answer))
        .then(answer => incomingPcContainer.pc.setLocalDescription(answer))
        .then() => {
            // send back the answer to the offerer
            invokeSignalRMethod('sendConnectionOfferAnswer', offererId, incomingPcContainer.pc.localDescription);
        });
});
```

And finally, the offerer receives the answer from the recipient:

```
chatHub.on('connectionOfferAnswered', (answererId, desc) => {
    outgoingPcContainer.pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(desc))
});
```

The code above makes the assumption that the remote end of a RtcPeerConnection never needs to handtle onnegotiationneeded based the comment about onnegotiationneeded [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/onnegotiationneeded):

> This negotiation should be carried out as the offerer, because some session changes cannot be negotiated as the answerer.

I interpreted this to mean that the *original* offerer of the connection will only ever need to renegotiate the connection. An alternative interpretation is that both sides can be expected to renegotiate, but whichever side does it should *become* the offerer. If it's the latter, then the code above will not handle renegotiation correctly when the answerer is expected to handle it.

So, can onnegotiationneeded fire from the answerer's side? In my testing I've not seen this and I'm struggling to get a gauge on what the specs say in this regard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can. Lets say you have an audio-only connection, e.g. from [this sample](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/audio/)
Then you want to add video to that connection so you paste the following into the console:

```
const video = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true});
pc2.onnegotiationneeded = () => console.log('pc2 ONN');
pc2.addTrack(video.getVideoTracks()[0], video);
```

ONN will fire on the answerer as it needs to create a new offer with an SDP that negotiates video.

The ["perfect negotiation" blog post](https://blog.mozilla.org/webrtc/perfect-negotiation-in-webrtc/) by Mozillas Jan-Ivar is a good reference for the rationale. Its unclear what the mdn article refers to, in particular since it doesn't go into detail.

Comment: Ahh, thanks for that. I had actually read that post, but largely skimmed it as the implementation seemed to rely on a feature that [isn't yet in Chrome](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5079977739419648). That aside, I think because I'm using separate `RtcPeerConnection`s, and only the outgoing offerer is the one adding or removing tracks to that connection, I think I avoid this case. Despite that, you've convinced me that it is possible so I'll make the required changes. Thanks again!